# MethodNotAllowedHttpException というエラーの原因がわからない

Tags: laravel

上記のエラーの原因がわかりません。
web.php辺りの記述が間違っているみたいですが、よくわかりません。
もしわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
必要なソースを言っていただければ追記します。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 情報が少なく丸投げになってしまっており、解決まで時間がかかりますよ。
「web.php辺りの記述が間違っているみたい」と思われるなら、そのコードを提示していただけませんか。
とりあえず、laravel のログと、web.php のルーティング部分は最低限必要かと思います。

Comment: 自力で調べて解決しました。ルーティングの問題でした。

Comment: user37276 さん、お疲れ様でした。スタック・オーバーフローでは、問題が自力で解決できた場合[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ができ、また推奨しています（他の人の助けになるかもしれないからです）。もし良ければ是非お願いいたします =)

Comment: すいません、具体的にはもう覚えてません。